# Music Website, embed live radio player, make invisible and keep control

Tags: html, iframe, audio-player

I need to create a music website for my IT course
So far I have all my pages but it must include a live radio page

I want to embed Capital FM onto that page

What I've done is added [this webpage](http://www.capitalfm.com/london/on-air/player/) into an iframe and made it 0x0 so it's hidden

```
<body>
    <iframe width="0" scrolling="no" height="0" frameborder="0" src="http://www.capitalfm.com/london/on-air/player/" seamless="seamless">
<body>
```

Now, I have to have a play and pause button so users can obviously stop the music if they wish.

My question, how would I keep the iframe hidden but have the play and pause buttons link to it and stop it?
Or even have the play and pause toggle a mute

Thanks

Comment: Regarding your specific question, you can just set -or unset- the iframe src with a button: `<button onclick="$('iframe").src=''">Pause</button><button onclick="$('iframe").src='http://www.capitalfm.com/london/on-air/player/'>Play</button>` this will works easily, but there is limitation if your parent page isn't https

Answer (score 0):

Use custom player and playing it: rtsp://cdn-the-2.musicradio.com:80/LiveAudio/Capital